# tunnel ssh for a mysql connection

Tags: mysql, ssh, unix, ssh-tunnel

I need to do an ssh tunnel to connect to a mysql server.
if i do :

```
me@local> mysql -h host -u user -p pwd
```

I get a 100 error

I have an ssh account on a distant server and this command works :

```
me@ssh-server> mysql -h host -u user -p pwd
```

I would like to create a ssh tunnel but i cannot figure out the propper command. Anybody got an idea ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the -L parameter for SSH to create a tunnel and redirect port 3306 (MySQL's port).

```
ssh -f me@ssh-server -L 3306:ssh-server:3306 -N
```

Then simply connect locally as you would on ssh-server. If you're on Windows locally, the parameters are pretty much the same for [plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

Comment: If MySQL is running on the ssh machine, change "ssh-server" to "localhost" if it fails to connect.  If MySQL is running on another host, use that other host's name in place of "ssh-server" in the -L option on the ssh command.  Then when connecting to the MySQL server from the local machine, use "-h localhost". on the mysql command.

Answer (score 0):

You better read more for port forwarding and SSH. read this http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-use-ssh-local-and-remote-port-forwarding.html or eventually a topic that I made recently might be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969264/noob-questions-for-svn-checkout-and-network-issues-regading-it. If you have further question reply to my answer.